# Find a header name then find the cell containing text total “total”

Tags: header, find

I have a data set containing header cells in column a, with the data below each header and a total at the bottom for each.
For the last header (“other”) I want to find the ‘total’ cell below it in col. A and then delete all rows from ‘total’ down as the data is not required.
I can find the header ‘other’, but struggling to then go to its related ‘total’ cell below. Any help much appreciated. Thanks

Tried to use the header address ‘other’ to then find the ‘total’ cell, but it keeps returning a ‘total’ cell way above the ‘other’ data.